# Почему не работает margin-top?

Tags: css

```css
.statistic-bg {
  background-color: #10c9c3;
  height: 240px;
}

.statistic {
  margin-top: 95px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="statistic-bg">
  <div class="layout">
    <div class="statistic">
      <i class="pe-7s-portfolio pe-2x pe-va"></i>
      <h2>512</h2>
      <p>projects completed</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

если добавить после div .stasistic-bg  `&nbsp` все срабатывает хорошо. Можно вообще пользоваться таким приёмом? Или это считается плохим тоном?

Comment: Вместо `margin` - `padding`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Происходит схлопывание вертикальных margin.

Если у родительского эл-та нет ограничивающих факторов (padding,border), то маргин переходит от внутреннего элемента к внешнему. Потом по старой схеме выбирается маргин: если они одноименные, то выбирается больший, если разноименные, то происходит сложение.
И в результате вы и получили свои странности.

Но, как быть, если нам это не нужно и мы хотим, чтобы див-родитель остался на своем месте, а див-ребенок отодвинулся на вниз?

Можно отменить это действие по отношению к родителю, есть несколько способов.

1. задавание padding родительскому блоку
2. задавание border родительскому блоку
3. задавание overflow родительскому блоку, любое значение кроме `visible` (работает везде, кроме старых ИЕ)

Пример задаем родителю `overflow:auto;`

```css
.statistic-bg {
  background-color: #10c9c3;
  height: 240px;
  overflow:auto;
}
.layout {
}
.statistic {
  margin-top: 95px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="statistic-bg">
  <div class="layout">
    <div class="statistic">
      <i class="pe-7s-portfolio pe-2x pe-va"></i>
      <h2>512</h2>
      <p>projects completed</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Официальная документация по этому вопросу https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html